# is there a way to overwrite the views Sort criteria?

Tags: 7, views

i have overwritten a field's output, and want to use it as the Sort criteria. so i must overwrite the Sort criteria?  is there a way to overwrite the views module Sort criteria?

the sort criteria is:

table `votingapi_vote`, the field `content_id`,which is $node->nid, the `vaule=1`. i want to to sort it by the number counts of the `vaule`. desc. HOW TO do it?

if i want to alter the  sort criteria in the template.php, is there a way to get it?

Answer (score 5):

Sure, just use [hook_views_query_alter()](http://api.lullabot.com/hook_views_query_alter).
You can intercept the view's query object and make any changes you need to it, including (but not limited to) adding/removing sort criteria.

[Better WHERE's for your Drupal forums with hook_views_query_alter](http://www.brianfending.com/content/better-wheres-your-drupal-forums-hookviewsqueryalter) and [Using hook_views_query_alter to change your views sort order](http://www.agileapproach.com/blog-entry/using-hookviewsqueryalter-change-your-views-sort-order-0) give some examples of how to alter a view query.

Comment: i don't know how to use this hook,could you give me an example. thank you.

Comment: Alex, i have updated the question. could you tell me how to use the hook_views_query_alter(). thank you.

Comment: Just an FYI, none of your links are working...